# Remove zero point from decimal for latitude and longtitude with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax

I have problem with return value with AJAX for latitude and longtitude data from server. I've created latitude and longtitude fields in MySQL database like this :

```
lat DECIMAL(10, 8) NOT NULL, lng DECIMAL(11, 8) NOT NULL
for example, i have stored data = lat : -6,4084848 , lng: 106,846609
```

but return value with ajax is always have extra zero  :

```
lat : -6.40848480  -> last number is extra zero
long: 106.83766610 -> last number is extra zero
```

How to remove extra zero number with JavaScript so I have precision value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the conversion function [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

```js
console.log(parseFloat(-6.40848480));
console.log(parseFloat(106.83766610));
```

Comment: Or maybe: someNumber/1